# MySQL - how do i group compare data with a previous row?

Tags: mysql, aggregation

I have a table with the following data:

```
mysql> select * from playground order by macAddress, locatedAt;
+------------+---------------------+--------------+
| macAddress | locatedAt           | status       |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:20:27 | connected    |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:30:27 | connected    |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:40:27 | disconnected |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:49:27 | connected    |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:50:27 | disconnected |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 01:55:27 | disconnected |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 02:05:27 | disconnected |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 02:17:27 | disconnected |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 02:27:27 | disconnected |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 02:47:27 | connected    |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 02:57:27 | connected    |
| device1    | 2014-08-11 03:50:27 | disconnected |
```

I need this summarized as below:

```
date         | hour | connected | disconnected | previouslyConnected
2014-08-11   |  1   |     1     |      0       |      0
2014-08-11   |  2   |     1     |      0       |      0
2014-08-11   |  3   |     0     |      0       |      1
```

As long as the device is connected once in an hour, disconnected doesn't matter. If a device has only 'disconnected' entries for a given hour, then it's in 'disconnected' state. And if a device is disconnected, then it gets into previouslyConnected state if the same device was in the 'connected' state in the previous hour. Otherwise it stays in the 'disconnected' state itself.

In the third row, device1 is in 'previouslyConnected" state because this device was connected in the previous hour (hour 2).

I have trouble getting the 'previouslyConnected' state devices;

With my current query, i am able to get everything except the last column.

```
SELECT TEMP.day, TEMP.hour, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TEMP.connected > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as connected,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TEMP.unconnected > 0 AND TEMP.connected < 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as unconnected
    from 

    (SELECT
        DATE(locatedAt) day,
        HOUR(locatedAt) hour,
        macAddress,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status='connected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as connected,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status='disconnected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as unconnected
    FROM
        playground
    GROUP BY 
        DATE(locatedAt), HOUR(locatedAt), macAddress) as TEMP

    GROUP BY TEMP.day, TEMP.hour;
```

Any pointers?

Comment: your results make no sense... you have 3 connected on hour 1 in the data but only show a count of 1?

Comment: if thats how you want it laid out when would disconnected be counted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use user-defined variable in order to check previous state of result ,in inner query i have used `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate all the statuses in the descending order of `locatedAt` so it will generate comma separated string of statuses in descending order and by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` i have picked the first status which is the last state of the machine, and i have stored the last state from the expression `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`status`ORDER BY locatedAt DESC),',',1)` in `@prev` variable ,and the a `CASE` statement to check the if it was connected in previous row the show 1 else 0

```
SELECT TEMP.day, TEMP.hour, 
    SUM(TEMP.connected > 0) as connected,
    SUM(TEMP.unconnected > 0 AND TEMP.connected < 1) as unconnected,
    TEMP.previouslyConnected
    FROM 
    (
SELECT
        DATE(locatedAt) day,
        HOUR(locatedAt) hour,
        macAddress,
        SUM(status='connected') as connected,
        SUM(status='disconnected') as unconnected,
        CASE WHEN @prev = 'connected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END previouslyConnected,
       @prev:= SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`status` ORDER BY locatedAt DESC),',',1) 
    FROM
        playground
      JOIN (SELECT @prev:='') t
    GROUP BY 
        DATE(locatedAt), HOUR(locatedAt), macAddress
      ) as TEMP

    GROUP BY TEMP.day, TEMP.hour;
```

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d25b0/10)

Answer (score 0):

## ASSUMPTIONS:

- you want to show 1 when there is a connection in a specific hour - connected column
- you want to show 0 when there is a connection in a specific hour - disconnected column
- you want to show 1 when there is a connection in the previous hour but not one in the current hour that still has a disconnection - previously connected column
- you want to show 1 when there is a disconnection and not a previously connection in the last hour -disconnected column

## QUERY:

```
SELECT 
    day,
    hour,
    connected,
    disconnected,
    previouslyConnected
FROM
(   SELECT 
        t.day,
        t.hour,
        CASE WHEN t.connected > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS connected,
        IF((CASE WHEN t.connected > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND @A = 0, 1, 0) AS disconnected,
        IF((CASE WHEN t.connected > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND @A = 1, 1, 0) AS previouslyConnected,
        @A := CASE WHEN t.connected > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM
    (   SELECT 
        DATE(locatedAt) AS 'day',
        HOUR(locatedAt) AS 'hour',
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'connected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS connected,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'disconnected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unconnected
    FROM playground
    GROUP BY HOUR(locatedAt) , DATE(locatedAt)
    ) t
) t1;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6948c/8)

## OUTPUT:

```
+-------------+------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|date         | hour | connected | disconnected | previouslyConnected |
+-------------+------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|2014-08-11   |  1   |     1     |      0       |      0              |
|2014-08-11   |  2   |     1     |      0       |      0              |
|2014-08-11   |  3   |     0     |      0       |      1              |
+-------------+------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without @variables by `LEFT JOIN`ing to the previous hour:

```
    SELECT DATE(p.locatedAt) day,
           HOUR(p.locatedAt) hour,
           SUM(p.status='connected') != 0 connected,
           SUM(p.status='disconnected') 
             AND NOT SUM(p.status='connected') unconnected,
           SUM(p.status='disconnected') 
             AND NOT SUM(p.status='connected')         
             AND COALESCE(SUM(pp.connected),0) != 0 previously_connected
      FROM playground p
 LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT EXTRACT(DAY_HOUR FROM locatedAt) d_h,
             SUM(status='connected') connected
        FROM playground
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY_HOUR FROM locatedAt),
             macAddress
           ) pp
        ON pp.d_h = EXTRACT(DAY_HOUR FROM p.locatedAt) - 1
  GROUP BY day,
           hour
  ORDER BY day,
           hour
```